# React Node Telegram bot problem with mainButtonClicked

Tags: reactjs, node.js, button, telegram-bot

I had a problem with sending data to the server and then having this data sent to me in the telegram bot.

When the 'Buy' button *(mainButtonClicked)* is pressed, nothing happens, nothing is sent to the server either, but if you configure the button to send data to the server when you press 'Add', then everything is sent.

**Here is the code on github, the main reasons are in the sections:**
tg-web-app-node/index.js and in tg-web-appreact/src/components/ProductList/ProductList.jsx

**Link:**
https://github.com/Topicesst/tg-web-app-node.git
https://github.com/Topicesst/tg-web-app-react.git

**Here is the problematic code:**

```
const getTotalPrice = (items = []) => {
     return items.reduce((acc, item) => {
         return acc += item.price
     }, 0)
}

const ProductList = () => {
     const [addedItems, setAddedItems] = useState([]);
     const {tg, queryId} = useTelegram();

     const onSendData = useCallback(() => {
         const data = {
             products: addedItems,
             totalPrice: getTotalPrice(addedItems),
             queryId,
         }
         fetch('http://80.85.143.220:8000/web-data', {
             method: 'POST',
             headers: {
                 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
             },
             body: JSON.stringify(data)
         })
     }, [addedItems])

    useEffect(() => {
         tg.onEvent('mainButtonClicked', onSendData)
         return () => {
             tg.offEvent('mainButtonClicked', onSendData)
         }
     }, [onSendData])


     const onAdd = (product) => {
         const alreadyAdded = addedItems.find(item => item.id === product.id);
         let newItems = [];

         if(alreadyAdded) {
             newItems = addedItems.filter(item => item.id !== product.id);
         } else {
             newItems = [...addedItems, product];
         }

         setAddedItems(newItems)

         if(newItems.length === 0) {
             tg.MainButton.hide();
         } else {
             tg.MainButton.show();
             tg.MainButton.setParams({
                 text: `Buy ${getTotalPrice(newItems)}`
             })
         }
     }

     return (
         <div className={'list'}>
             {products.map(item => (
                 <ProductItem
                     product={item}
                     onAdd={onAdd}
                     className={'item'}
                 />
             ))}
         </div>
     );
};

export default ProductList;
```

Bduu is very grateful for the help, because even acquaintances could not help solve the problem (

I checked whether the button responds and whether it sends at least some data to the server - it does.